# Give commands to localhost by subprocess.call

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am new to python and Linux. I am trying to execute a bash command from python which gives a command to localhost.

Initally i tried with os.system

```
os.system('echo "(primitive-load \"/opt/doc/test.txt\")" |nc localhost xxxxx')
```

I have successfully called several commands using os.system. But this particular command with the file path does not execute. so i tried with subprocess.call

```
subprocess.call( 'echo "(primitive-load \"/opt/doc/test.txt\")" |nc localhost xxxxx')
```

But threw the following error.

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have also tried the following

```
command = 'echo "(primitive-load \"/opt/doc/test.scm\")"|nc localhost xxxxx;'
process = os.popen(command)
```

Any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following maybe it can help in your situation:

```
import os

command = 'echo "test"'
process = os.popen(command)
output = str(process.read())

print output
```

Hope this helps don't forget to upvote

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 'echo "test"' works!!. But with the file path it is not working. Just tried.

Comment: Use cat instead of echo then

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

```
loadData='echo "(primitive-load \\"/opt/doc/body.txt\\")" |nc localhost xxxxxx'
subprocess.call(loadData,shell=True)
```